# find the nearest previous negative value in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
t <- c(103,104,108,120,127,129,140,142,150,151,160,177,178,183,186,187,191,194,198,199)
w <- c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1)

df <- data_frame(t, w)

> dput(df)
structure(list(t = c(103, 104, 108, 120, 127, 129, 140, 142, 
150, 151, 160, 177, 178, 183, 186, 187, 191, 194, 198, 199), 
w = c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 
-1, 1, 1, -1, -1)), .Names = c("t", "w"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> df
# A tibble: 20 x 2
       t     w
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1   103  1.00
 2   104  1.00
 3   108  1.00
 4   120 -1.00
 5   127 -1.00
 6   129 -1.00
 7   140 -1.00
 8   142 -1.00
 9   150  1.00
10   151  1.00
11   160 -1.00
12   177 -1.00
13   178  1.00
14   183  1.00
15   186  1.00
16   187 -1.00
17   191  1.00
18   194  1.00
19   198 -1.00
20   199 -1.00
```

Now, if the value in `w` is **larger than zero**, find the ***nearest previous* negative** `w`, and assign the difference between the corresponding `t` values to a new column `d`. Otherwise, `d` is equal to zero. I.e. the desired output should look like this:

```
       t     w   d
     103  1.00  NA   (there is no previous w < 0)
     104  1.00  NA   (there is no previous w < 0)
     108  1.00  NA   (there is no previous w < 0)
     120 -1.00   0
     127 -1.00   0
     129 -1.00   0
     140 -1.00   0
     142 -1.00   0
     150  1.00   8   = 150 - 142
     151  1.00   9   = 151 - 142
     160 -1.00   0
     177 -1.00   0
     178  1.00   1   = 178 - 177
     183  1.00   6   = 183 - 177
     186  1.00   9   = 186 - 177
     187 -1.00   0
     191  1.00   4   = 191 - 187
     194  1.00   7   = 194 - 187
     198 -1.00   0
     199 -1.00   0
```

(The `NA`s above might be zero as well.)

Since yesterday I'm trying to attack this problem using `findInterval()`, `which()`, etc. but without success. Another way I was thinking about is to introduce somehow a variable shift in `lag()` function...

Ideally, I would like to have a `tidyverse`-like solution.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you might find `tidyr::fill` helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using data.table** (since tidyverse currently has no non-equi joins):

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(df)

DT[, v := 0]
DT[w > 0, v := 
  DT[w < 0][.SD, on=.(t < t), mult="last", i.t - x.t]
]

      t  w  v
 1: 103  1 NA
 2: 104  1 NA
 3: 108  1 NA
 4: 120 -1  0
 5: 127 -1  0
 6: 129 -1  0
 7: 140 -1  0
 8: 142 -1  0
 9: 150  1  8
10: 151  1  9
11: 160 -1  0
12: 177 -1  0
13: 178  1  1
14: 183  1  6
15: 186  1  9
16: 187 -1  0
17: 191  1  4
18: 194  1  7
19: 198 -1  0
20: 199 -1  0
```

It initializes the new column to 0, then replaces it on the subset of rows where `w > 0`. The replacement uses a join of the subset of data, `.SD`, where `w > 0` to the part of the table where `w < 0`, `DT[w < 0]`. The join syntax is `x[i, on=, j]` where in this case...

- `x = DT[w < 0]`
- `i = .SD = DT[w > 0]`

The join uses each row of `i` to look up rows in `x` based on the rules in `on=`. When multiple matches are found, we take only the last (`mult = "last"`).

`j` is what we use the join to do, here calculate the difference between two columns. To disambiguate columns from each table, we use prefixes `x.*` and `i.*`.

---

**Using cummax.** I'm not sure if this generalizes, but it works for the example:

```
DT[, v := t - cummax(t*(w < 0))]
DT[cumsum(w < 0) == 0, v := NA]
```

I guess this requires that the `t` column is sorted in increasing order.

Comment: Both variants are great since the `t` column is always ascending here. And the second one might easily be realised also in `dplyr`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A tidverse way:

First, make an intermediate column (t2) with NA if positive and and t if neg

```
df <- mutate(df, t2 = case_when(w > 0 ~ as.numeric(NA), TRUE ~ t)) 

#fill NA in t2 so that for each row, t2 is value of t when w was last neg
df <- fill(df, t2)

#> df
# A tibble: 20 x 3
#       t     w    t2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   103     1    NA
# 2   104     1    NA
# 3   108     1    NA
# 4   120    -1   120
# 5   127    -1   127
# 6   129    -1   129
# 7   140    -1   140
# 8   142    -1   142
# 9   150     1   142
#10   151     1   142
#11   160    -1   160
#12   177    -1   177
#13   178     1   177
#14   183     1   177
#15   186     1   177
#16   187    -1   187
#17   191     1   187
#18   194     1   187
#19   198    -1   198
#20   199    -1   199
```

Then subtract t2 from t

```
df$d <- with(df, t - t2)

#> df
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#       t     w    t2     d
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   103     1    NA    NA
# 2   104     1    NA    NA
# 3   108     1    NA    NA
# 4   120    -1   120     0
# 5   127    -1   127     0
# 6   129    -1   129     0
# 7   140    -1   140     0
# 8   142    -1   142     0
# 9   150     1   142     8
#10   151     1   142     9
#11   160    -1   160     0
#12   177    -1   177     0
#13   178     1   177     1
#14   183     1   177     6
#15   186     1   177     9
#16   187    -1   187     0
#17   191     1   187     4
#18   194     1   187     7
#19   198    -1   198     0
#20   199    -1   199     0
```

Comment: This is also very nice and can be piped. Thank you!